# Change variable value on button click

Tags: javascript, html, variables, button

very new to JS, I'm struggling with my current project: Trying to insert some HTML via a function if a `variable = "yes"`. The variable value will change on a button click.
I've been using firebug to look at the variable value - it doesn't seem to be changing on the button click.

Was hoping someone would be kind enough to help.

I THINK my main issue is with setting the variable value - but I could of course be wrong so I've attached a codepen version for good luck :)

HTML:

```
<button id="butterbutton" onclick="imageAdd('yes'); ">
  <img id="worldimg" src="http://butterybeast.hol.es/world.png"></img>                
</button>
```

JS:

```
var beast
function imageAdd(choice) {
  beast = choice;
}

if (beast = "yes" ) {
  function imagemap () {
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML += '<img> an image map goes here';
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/Puffincat/pen/Nrdgrz?editors=1010

Comment: `if (beast = "yes" ) ` should be   `if (beast == "yes" )`, you are assigning instead of evaluating

Comment: That makes sense, however still not doing the job! :( Probably the start of many a issues!

Comment: `function imageAdd(choice) {
   document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML += '<img> an image map        goes here';
}`

Comment: Ah you are a genius!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just a couple of problems with your code. The first is this:

```
if (beast = "yes") {
```

In this case, you're assigning `"yes"` to `beast`, not comparing it. Change it to

```
if (beast == "yes") {
```

Next, your code at the bottom (`if (beast == "yes") { ...`) is only run at the start. Instead, you want that code to run whenever the variable is updated. Move it into your `imageAdd` function or somewhere else where you update the UI then call it from `imageAdd`. While you're at it, remove that `imagemap` function declaration. It doesn't make sense to declare a function inside of an `if` statement.

```
var beast;
function imageAdd(choice) {
  beast = choice;
  updateUI();
}

function updateUI() {
  if (beast == "yes") {
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML += '<img> an image map goes here';
  }
}
```

Comment: Find the solution, not just helping to asphalt the wrong road

Comment: @AliTorabi I have no idea what that means.

Comment: He just wanted to add HTML, with cliking

Comment: @AliTorabi I know. They wanted to update a value when they click and if that value matches another value, update the HTML. This accomplishes that goal.

Comment: @AliTorabi Well, that's not for you to decide. This is a perfectly valid situation and a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: In case of solving the worlds problem you are write, in case of person, you need to see what they need. Are you going to do everything a customer asks or will help him to decide better mike?

Comment: @AliTorabi What is your problem? There's nothing wrong with what they want and I even encouraged some best practices by separating out the UI updates from the primary event handler. If you think you have a better idea of what they need, both in terms of functionality and in terms of education, then write your own answer.

Comment: The he is a she - just FYI. I appreciate both of your suggestions, thank you both. I do believe that Mike's solution suits what I needed for the website I'm making better, if it's right or wrong on how I've done this is probably a question for a few years time when I've finished uni!

Answer (score 0):

You have a function `imagemap` wrapped in a conditional but you aren't calling that function.

Also for your conditional, `beast` will always be `null` since the conditional is called straight away.

Consider the following adjustment

```
var beast;

function imagemap () {
  document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML += '<img> an image map goes here';
}

function imageAdd(choice) {
  beast = choice;

  if (beast === "yes" ) {
    imagemap();
  }
}
```

Comment: Small correction: `beast` would be `undefined`, not `null`. They're different values.